# Python -Google Search - How to set flexible results picking

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some pages accessing them by Google Search and I need to add some restricted words list.

Lets say  that 4 top results for Python in Google search is:

- Welcome to Python.org 
  https://www.python.org/
- Python (programming language) - Wikipedia
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)
- Python Tutorial - W3Schools 
  https://www.w3schools.com/python/
- Learn Python - Free Interactive Python Tutorial 
  https://www.learnpython.org/

Then I would like to open 1st result that does not contains words like:
[".org", "wikipedia"] in search description and/or link -(So in  this case script would open w3schools)

I was trying to get work done with different selectors / and getting whole google search page document but so far no positive results came :

```
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q') 
search.send_keys("Gran Hotel La Florida G.L Monumento")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) # hit return after you enter search text time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('LC20lb').click()
```

This opens the first non-advertisement result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can update your selector to click on required link:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h3[@class="LC20lb" and not(contains(text(), "org")) and not(contains(text(), "wikipedia"))]').click()
```

This will exclude results that contains substring `"org"` and `"wikipedia"`

Comment: I was really hoping for something like this however: 

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //h3[@class="LC20lb" | not(contain(text(), "booking")) | not(contain(text(), "tripadvisor"))] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//h3[@class="LC20lb" and not(contain(text(), "org")) and not(contain(text(), "wikipedia"))]').click()

However:
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h3[@class="LC20lb"]').click()
works finr

Comment: @ArturGorczyński , yeah, my fault :) replace `contain` with `contains`

Comment: With "contains" the same error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//h3[@class="LC20lb"] and not (contains(text(), "org")' is not a valid XPath expression.

:< It drives me mad -.- I think it might be fault of google search structure ?? But I am definitely not an expert

Comment: @ArturGorczyński do not close the braket after first predicate: note that you used `[@class="LC20lb"] and...`, but it should be `[@class="LC20lb" and...`

Comment: Och dusch I am dumb :| Still struggling with few minor problems but YAY it is working ;) Thanks mate!
In the mean time I found somehting like this"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//*[not(contains(text(), 'org'))][@class='LC20lb']")).click()"

Also working quite nice. Thnaks again !!!

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

Maybe something like the following which excludes based on the `href` (also limits to href starting with http and removes those with class `.fl`. `:not` pseudo class is passed a list of conditions - in this case mostly substrings to exclude via contains operator.

```
.r [href^=http]:not(.fl,[href*=\.org],[href*=wikipedia])
```

---

Test case below tested with a number of different country Google searches

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.google.com/')
d.find_element_by_css_selector('[title=Search]').send_keys('python')
WebDriverWait(d, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[type=submit]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.r')))
soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
links =  [link['href'] for link in soup.select('.r [href^=http]:not(.fl,[href*=\.org],[href*=wikipedia])')]
print(links)
```

Comment: Always with EC.element  to be clicable i get
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I think because your local google search will have a different text string I think.  For the Google search button (the left of the two that appear at the bottom when you have input search term) -- you need to inspect the element and see what the value of the  _value_ attribute is called in your language. In English it says Google  Search.

Comment: you might also get away with  using [type="submit"] as the selector instead of [value="Google Search"]

Comment: I have updated with version that works across  countries.